# Normalize Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am asking a question for the first time so please let me know if any more clarification is required on the question and I will try to edit the question to make it more clear.

Given multiple ways to achieve an event and given their probabilities for eg Scoring >95 marks on a test can be done with two possible ways - 1) Studying hard (Probability for this is 80%) . 2) Not Studying/Chilling (Probability is 40%). How do I find total maximum probability if cumulative probability is > 1. In short how do I normalize probabilities?

Comment: Probabilities can never exceed 100%, so the events presented are mutually exclusive (as they seem to be), the numbers are wrong.

Comment: It seems you're saying that there are two cases of interest. The first, studying hard, will get you a good grade (scoring greater than 95) with probability 0.8. The second, not studying, will get you that same good grade, but with probability 0.4. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saying that the probability of studying hard is 80% and the probability of not studying hard is 40% then this is wrong, because these two probabilities should add to 100%. If you know that the probability of studying hard is twice as high as the probability of not studying hard then the probability of studying hard must be 2/3 (about 67%) since the total probability must add to 100%.

If, on the other hand you're saying that if you study hard you have an 80% chance of doing well on the test and if you don't study hard you have a 40% chance of doing well, then you can define $s$ to be the probability of studying hard. In that case, the probability of doing well on the test is

$$s(.8) + (1-s)(.4)$$.

Note that this is automatically a number between zero and one (or between 0% and 100%) because $s, 1-s$ add to one and they're being multiplied by numbers between zero and one. Of course, you still don't know what this probability is without knowing how likely it is that someone studies hard, but you can already see that it is constrained properly.